# How to replace options in a Select2 select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to dynamically clear a [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) option list, and reload it with new data. Everything I read tells me that I can set the data like I'm doing, but it only appends data, and doesn't clear it.

```js
$("#optioner").select2();

$("#doit").click(function() {
  $("#optioner").select2({
    data: [{
      id: "real1",
      text: "Real 1"
    }, {
      id: "real2",
      text: "Real 2"
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<h1>Demo</h1>

<select id="optioner" class="select2">
  <option value="fake1">Fake 1</option>
  <option value="fake2">Fake 2</option>
</select>

<input id="doit" type="button" value="Real It Up">
```

I [fiddled that up](https://jsfiddle.net/Kieveli/Lhhe8t44/) for yall.

Comment: Maybe you must add option allowClear, placeholder and change event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select2 doesn't provide a way to totally clear the options before adding them with the `data` option, simply because it can already be done with jQuery `.empty()` function.

```
$("#optioner").empty()
    .select2({ data: /* ... */ });
```

From [issue #3877](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3877#issuecomment-152368428):

> This is the intended behavior of the `data` option. When Select2
>   is initialized with `data`, it converts the array of data objects into
>   `<option>` elements that it can use.
>
> So when you reinitialize it, it creates a second set of `<option>`
>   elements.
>
> > If not, how do I re-populate the list of options / data for Select2?
>
> You can clear out the existing options by calling .empty() on your
>   original select.
>
> ```
> $("select").empty();
> ```
>
> Note that this will reset any existing selections

```js
$("#optioner").select2();

$("#doit").click(function() {
  var $elem = $("#optioner");
  $elem.empty()
    .select2({
      data: [{
        id: "real1",
        text: "Real 1"
      }, {
        id: "real2",
        text: "Real 2"
      }]
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<h1>Demo</h1>

<select id="optioner" class="select2">
  <option value="fake1">Fake 1</option>
  <option value="fake2">Fake 2</option>
</select>

<input id="doit" type="button" value="Real It Up">
```